# How to let Eclipse accept the canvas tag?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, html, aptana

I installed the Aptana plugin in my Eclipse, and I use canvas tag in my html file. 
I find that the Eclipse can't recognize the canvas tag, it highlight my canvas tags, and display follow msg:

> < canvas > is not recognized

How can I fix this problem? thx in advance.

Comment: It would be better to make the question more generic: how can I change Eclipse to make it accept HTML5 tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is most likely coming from the Tidy HTML validator packaged with Aptana's version of Eclipse.  If you open the preferences for your HTML browser within Aptana, you can add a regular expression to filter the validation errors.

This can be done by going to the Window > Preferences dialog window.  Then, expand Aptana > HTML and select 'Validation'.

The filter would probably look like this:

> .*<canvas> is not recognized.*

Comment: I'm using Aptana Studio 3 (beta) and I was not able to find your option. Any idea?

Comment: @sorin -- malaxuer meant Aptana > Editors > HTML > Validation.  pasting the recommended filter text into a new filter in the 'Filter for Validation View Errors' eliminated the <canvas> complaint for me.

Answer (score 5):

The specific rule under the Aptana>Editors>HTML>Validation filter is

`.*<\s*canvas\s*> is not recognized.*`

Doing something more generic like `.* is not recognized.*` lets any Bad Tag in

Answer (score 1):

The answer, in clear terms, is to go to the HTML>Validation view under preferences as [Malaxeur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152621/malaxeur) said (for Aptana2 on OSX it was Aptana Studio>Preferences, then Aptana>Editors>HTML>Validation), and **create** a **new** rule that resembles the following.

```
.* is not recognized.*
```

that's what worked for me. how or why it works, i can't explain.

Answer (score 1):

The error will disappear if using the HTML5 doctype and a more recent version of Eclipse. I'm running Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (Build id: 20110218-0911) and do not have this issue.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true, JTidy still complains

Comment: @Gabe In that case it sounds like JTidy isn't respecting the default validation mechanisms provided by Eclipse. Have they corrected this issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's already fixed in the current Aptana 3 beta. But in Aptana 2 it's still a problem.
To allow not all, but multiple HTML5 Tags you could do it with a filter rule like that:

```
<(nav|header|section|article|canvas)> is not recognized.
```

Of course there are some more tags to consider. Just add the ones you need.