# Meteor aptana and templates

Tags: aptana, meteor

Im using aptana to code with meteor on windows (it has nice ota SSH/FTP editing which is why I use it). But the `<template>` tags are a meteor feature so it spits out warnings when using them.

Is there a nicer editor for windows to handle my files with SSH/FTP? Or even better a way to to add `<template>` to aptana?

[image]

The warning is specifically:

[image]

Because templates encapsulate all the html, everything gets underlined!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to `Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation` you can go through the various validators (HTML Syntax Validator and HTML Tidy Validator are probably the relevant ones for you).

Under HTML Tidy, you can clickdown 'Elements' and change 'Unrecognized elements' from 'Warning' to 'Info' or 'Ignore'.

In the HTML Syntax Validator you can add regular expressions for errors to be ignored like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216762/how-to-let-eclipse-accept-the-canvas-tag).

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) is a nice editor for Javascript code.

Although it doesn't come with FTP support by default, but you can configure it using instructions given [here](http://www.brentmountford.com/tutorials/sublime-text-2-sftp-setup-usage/).

Hope it helps.